¿Cómo puedo utilizar JFlex en VS Code?
necesito hacer un analizador léxico y quiero utilizar jflex junto con vs code pero no se como, he buscado información en la pagina oficial pero solo me indica como instalar en Windows
intentos
Cree un proyecto de java con la opción de "no build tools" y trate de exportar la librería de Jflex en la carpeta de "referenced libraries"

¿y que has intentado?

Cree un proyecto de java con la opción de "no build tools" y trate de exportar la librería de Jflex en la carpeta de "referenced libraries"

Si vas a programar en Java siendo novato, es más sencillo usar un IDE con build tools: Eclipse o IntelliJ junto a Maven/Gradle simplifica mucho la vida. En VS tendrás que instalar extensiones para Java y requiere más trabajo manual

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

@MacbethCastillo ¿y obtuviste algún error en concreto?
